# Python 3.7 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'has'

Tags: django, python-3.7

Using Python 3.7.3 , PIP 19.3.1 , Django 2.2, I need to check whether an object is string or not and started by using this code:

```
if not isinstance(math,  basestring):
    math = latex(math)
    return '<script type="math/tex; mode=display">{}</script>'.format(math)
```

Using 'str' instead  of 'basestring' causes the script to output an error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'get' error
```

I then tried the following code

```py
def format_math_display(self, math):
    try:
      if not isinstance(math,  basestring):
         math = latex(math)
         return '<script type="math/tex; mode=display">{} 
                 </script>'.format(math)
    except Exception:
         pass
```

But it also leads to an(other) error:

```
AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute 'has'
Request Method:  POST
Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:  2.2.6
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'has'

Python Executable:  C:\Users\Vasundhara\Envs\calculate\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\wamp64\\www\\Python3Django2\\Calculate',
 'C:\\Users\\Vasundhara\\Envs\\calculate\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Vasundhara\\Envs\\calculate\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Vasundhara\\Envs\\calculate\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Vasundhara\\Envs\\calculate\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\vasundhara\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\vasundhara\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Vasundhara\\Envs\\calculate',
 'C:\\Users\\Vasundhara\\Envs\\calculate\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 26 Oct 2019 04:08:58 +0000
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Rephrased the question and formatted code properly. The « _(Using 'str' instead  of 'basestring')_ » is still confusing.